# using sed to find, compare and replace text

Tags: sed

I have a text in a single file

Quiz

```
Worker(Thomas) works in .......... 
Worker(Alfred) works in .......... 
Worker(Albert) works in ..........
```

Answer

```
Worker(Thomas) works for company(google) 
Worker(Alfred) works for company(apple)
Worker(Albert) works for company(Microsoft)
```

I wish to replace the empty dotted  lines in "Quiz" from information given in "Answer" by using sed based text search, matching and replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `awk` for this task. Assuming you have two separate files `Quiz` and `Answer`in the same directory, `cd` into that directory and run the following command in the terminal:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$4; next}{$4=a[$1]; print}' > Answered_Quiz Answer Quiz
```

A new file named `Answered_Quiz` will be created in the same directory and it will contain the desired result.

If all the lines are in one file, you can split it first:

run the following command replacing `FileName` with your text file name:

```
awk '$4 ~ /(^[\.]+$)/' > Quiz FileName
```

to make the Quiz file.

then run the following command replacing `FileName` with your text file name:

```
awk '$4 !~ /(^[\.]+$)/' > Answer FileName
```

to get the Answer file. Your original file will not be affected

---

Or if all the lines are in one file and you prefer not to split the file, use the following code in a script file (or you can just copy and paste it in the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) from within the same directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

pat1="(^[\.]+$)"


while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
                do

                        if [[ "$f4" =~ $pat1 ]]

                        then
                        # change Quiz in the following line with your source file name
                        a4=$(awk -v ff1="$f1" '$4 !~ /(^[\.]+$)/ && $1 == ff1 {print $4}' "Quiz")

                        echo "$f1 $f2 $f3 $a4" >> "Answered_Quiz" 
                        fi
                # change Quiz in the following line with your source file name
                done < "Quiz"
```

A new file named Answered_Quiz will be created in the same directory and it will contain the desired result.

Best of luck

Comment: Answer and Quiz are in the same file.

Comment: @pasmon Then, split it. Run  `awk '$4 ~ /(^[\.]+$)/' > Quiz FileName` to make the Quiz file, replacing `FileName` with your text file name and then run `awk '$4 !~ /(^[\.]+$)/' > Answer FileName` to get the Answer file. Your original file will not be affected.

Comment: Actually my aim is to target similar problems in a stand alone file, can it be done.

Comment: @pasmon It can be done. I think a bash script would be a better and faster solution for this. At least for me.

Comment: I aim at a bash script anyway